# Preserving styles using python's xlrd,xlwt, and xlutils.copy

Tags: python, xlrd, xlwt

I'm using `xlrd`, `xlutils.copy`, and `xlwt` to open up a template file, copy it, fill it with new values, and save it.

However, there doesn't seem to be any easy way to preserve the formatting of the cells; it always gets blown away and set to blank.  Is there any simple way I can do this?

Thanks!
/YGA

A sample script:

```
from xlrd import open_workbook
from xlutils.copy import copy
rb = open_workbook('output_template.xls',formatting_info=True)
rs = rb.sheet_by_index(0)
wb = copy(rb)
ws = wb.get_sheet(0)
for i,cell in enumerate(rs.col(8)):
    if not i:
        continue
    ws.write(i,2,22,plain)
wb.save('output.xls')
```

Versions:

- `xlrd`: 0.7.1
- `xlwt`: 0.7.2

Answer (score 57):

There are two parts to this.

First, you must enable the reading of formatting info when opening the source workbook. The copy operation will then copy the formatting over.

```
import xlrd
import xlutils.copy

inBook = xlrd.open_workbook('input.xls', formatting_info=True)
outBook = xlutils.copy.copy(inBook)
```

Secondly, you must deal with the fact that changing a cell value resets the formatting of that cell.

This is less pretty; I use the following hack where I manually copy the formatting index (`xf_idx`) over:

```
def _getOutCell(outSheet, colIndex, rowIndex):
    """ HACK: Extract the internal xlwt cell representation. """
    row = outSheet._Worksheet__rows.get(rowIndex)
    if not row: return None

    cell = row._Row__cells.get(colIndex)
    return cell

def setOutCell(outSheet, col, row, value):
    """ Change cell value without changing formatting. """
    # HACK to retain cell style.
    previousCell = _getOutCell(outSheet, col, row)
    # END HACK, PART I

    outSheet.write(row, col, value)

    # HACK, PART II
    if previousCell:
        newCell = _getOutCell(outSheet, col, row)
        if newCell:
            newCell.xf_idx = previousCell.xf_idx
    # END HACK

outSheet = outBook.get_sheet(0)
setOutCell(outSheet, 5, 5, 'Test')
outBook.save('output.xls')
```

This preserves almost all formatting. Cell comments are not copied, though.

Comment: but cell referencing in the other sheets are missing!

Comment: small tweak suggestion: rowIndex first then colIndex in the arguments could be more intuitive for most

Comment: Setting `formatting_info` to `True` was enough to preserve the formatting

Answer (score 12):

Here's an example of usage of code that I'll propose as a patch against xlutils 1.4.1

```
# coding: ascii

import xlrd, xlwt

# Demonstration of copy2 patch for xlutils 1.4.1

# Context:
# xlutils.copy.copy(xlrd_workbook) -> xlwt_workbook
# copy2(xlrd_workbook) -> (xlwt_workbook, style_list)
# style_list is a conversion of xlrd_workbook.xf_list to xlwt-compatible styles

# Step 1: Create an input file for the demo
def create_input_file():
    wtbook = xlwt.Workbook()
    wtsheet = wtbook.add_sheet(u'First')
    colours = 'white black red green blue pink turquoise yellow'.split()
    fancy_styles = [xlwt.easyxf(
        'font: name Times New Roman, italic on;'
        'pattern: pattern solid, fore_colour %s;'
         % colour) for colour in colours]
    for rowx in xrange(8):
        wtsheet.write(rowx, 0, rowx)
        wtsheet.write(rowx, 1, colours[rowx], fancy_styles[rowx])
    wtbook.save('demo_copy2_in.xls')

# Step 2: Copy the file, changing data content
# ('pink' -> 'MAGENTA', 'turquoise' -> 'CYAN')
# without changing the formatting

from xlutils.filter import process,XLRDReader,XLWTWriter

# Patch: add this function to the end of xlutils/copy.py
def copy2(wb):
    w = XLWTWriter()
    process(
        XLRDReader(wb,'unknown.xls'),
        w
        )
    return w.output[0][1], w.style_list

def update_content():
    rdbook = xlrd.open_workbook('demo_copy2_in.xls', formatting_info=True)
    sheetx = 0
    rdsheet = rdbook.sheet_by_index(sheetx)
    wtbook, style_list = copy2(rdbook)
    wtsheet = wtbook.get_sheet(sheetx)
    fixups = [(5, 1, 'MAGENTA'), (6, 1, 'CYAN')]
    for rowx, colx, value in fixups:
        xf_index = rdsheet.cell_xf_index(rowx, colx)
        wtsheet.write(rowx, colx, value, style_list[xf_index])
    wtbook.save('demo_copy2_out.xls')

create_input_file()
update_content()
```

Comment: A better fix would be xlwt adding a `wb.write_value(row, col, value)`.  This works, but has a lot of code stink in my book, working around a poor implementation of xlwt.

Comment: Did this ever happen?