# how to write into XLS with python with format unchanged?

Tags: python, format, xls

Is there a way to write something into an XLS file with python while keeping the initial format of this XLS file unchanged (such as font size, cell background color, etc)Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe have a look at xlrd, xlwt, xlutils:

http://www.python-excel.org/

I have found it pretty useful in the past.

Comment: Thank you! I tried the xlutils.copy, but it changed the initial styles completely...

Comment: This should help, following similar advice from @john machin I got it to work: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3723793/preserving-styles-using-pythons-xlrd-xlwt-and-xlutils-copy

Answer (score 0):

If you can  go for XML serializations of Office documents. Also have a look at ... http://www.python-excel.org/

Answer (score 0):

You could also use [pywin32](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pywin32/) if you are using Windows

Comment: @ladyfafa: Fabio means: Use the COM interface in pywin32 to use Excel's COM interface directly. This is the most powerful and most flexible solution (you can do everything you can do in Excel), but you must be running on a Windows system with Excel installed.

Answer (score 0):

If the available tools like xlrd, xlwt, and xlutils don't work, you may have to fall back to programmatically editing the file with Excel via COM.  Of course, you'll need a copy of Excel, have to work from Windows, and it will be slower than other approaches.

Comment: Excel COM is also the only way of creating/editing Excel 2007/2010 worksheets at the moment. I know I'd like a non-COM solution to creating Excel 2007 worksheets and ideally signing them as well.  (Yes I know the OP asked for xls specifically. )