# xlwings: Save and Close

Tags: python, excel, xlwings

I am trying to find out how to save and close to an existing workbook using xlwings after writing in it:

```
import xlwings as xw

list_of_values = [1, 2, 3]
workbook_path = 'abc.xlsx'
wb = xw.Book(workbook_path)
ws = wb.sheets['sheet1']
ws.range('E35').value = list_of_values
wb.save()
wb.close()
```

When I get to `wb.save(workbook_path)`, there is a prompt stating:
    'A file named abc.xlsx' already exists in this location. 
    Do you want to replace it?'

I want to overwrite the file immediately without the prompt coming up. According to the docs, `wb.save()` should automatically overwrite (see: https://docs.xlwings.org/en/v0.6.4/api.html). I have also tried `wb.save(workbook_path)` but the pop-up still appears.

Appreciate any help on this please.

p.s. - I am basically trying to write data into a pre-formatted excel sheet. If there are other ways that can preserve the formatting, I would be happy to try it. I have tried this but it throws an error at `if newCell`: [Easily write formatted Excel from Python: Start with Excel formatted, use it in Python, and regenerate Excel from Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9920935/easily-write-formatted-excel-from-python-start-with-excel-formatted-use-it-in)

Comment: You may need to specify the _full path_ when you specify the path to [`wb.save()`](https://docs.xlwings.org/en/v0.6.4/api.html#xlwings.Workbook.save): _"`path` (str, default None) – Full path to the workbook"_.

Comment: it worked perfectly! thank you. if you can add that as an answer i will mark it as accepted

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may need to specify the *full path* when you specify the path to [`wb.save()`](https://docs.xlwings.org/en/v0.6.4/api.html#xlwings.Workbook.save):

> *`path` (str, default None) – Full path to the workbook*.

It will save the file and overwrite without prompting. From their docs:

> ```
> >>> from xlwings import Workbook
> >>> wb = Workbook()
> >>> wb.save()
> >>> wb.save(r'C:\path\to\new_file_name.xlsx')
> ```