# How to preserve macro buttons in Excel when adding data with Python

Tags: python, excel, xlrd, xlwt

For a process I am maintaining, I have a script that creates a csv file and then I copy the csv file into an Excel workbook with buttons that activate macros.  This process works just fine.

I am trying to improve that process by writing a script that builds the workbook directly, thus eliminating a step.  I thought the best way to do that was to create a template workbook where the first worksheet has the macro button.  Then I would simply copy the template workbook, add in my data and save the new workbook under a new custom name.  My test code is below:

```
import csv, os, sys, xlrd, xlwt, xlutils, shutil
from copy import deepcopy
from xlutils import save
from xlutils.copy import copy

templatefile = 'N:\Tools\Scripts-DEV\Testing_Template.xls'
Destfile = 'N:\Tools\Scripts-DEV\Testing_Dest.xls'

shutil.copy(templatefile,Destfile)

# Works fine up to here.  
# If you look at the new file, it has the button that is in the template file.

rb = xlrd.open_workbook(Destfile)

rs = rb.sheet_by_index(0)

wb = copy(rb)  

wb.get_sheet(0).write(3, 0, 'Due Date')
wb.get_sheet(0).write(3, 1, 'Name')
wb.get_sheet(0).write(3, 3, 'Category')
wb.get_sheet(0).write(3, 4, 'Number')

wb.save(Destfile)
```

Here is where the problem shows up.  After you save, the macro button disappears.  I've been looking for a couple days but I haven't (yet) found a way to save the updated Excel file without losing the macro button.

I've been looking at [Preserving styles using python's xlrd,xlwt, and xlutils.copy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3723793/preserving-styles-using-pythons-xlrd-xlwt-and-xlutils-copy) but that doesn't quite meet my needs as I'm trying to preserve a button, not a style.

Does anyone know a way to do this?

I'm about to start looking at alternatives to `xlutils, xlrd and xlwt` as well, but I thought I'd ask here first.

Comment: Thinking that maybe copy didn't copy over the macro button, I thought I'd try using deepcopy() by putting in these lines:

    wb1 = deepcopy(rb)  
    wb = xlrd.open_workbook(wb1)

but that gets me the following error:

> File "N:\Tools\Scripts-DEV\Scan_Analysis_DEV\tcompliance8.py", line 25, i
n <module>
wb.get_sheet(0).write(3, 0, 'Due Date')
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\xlrd\__init__.py", line 984, in get_sheet
raise XLRDError("Can't load sheets after releasing resources.")
xlrd.biffh.XLRDError: Can't load sheets after releasing resources.

Answer (score 1):

From you comment part `C:\Python27\` I deduce that you are on Windows. In that case you are probably better off with using [pywin32](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pywin32/) and a template `.xls` or `.xlsm` file.

Open the file using `os.startfile(filename)` then connect using `workbook = win32com.client.GetObject(filename)`. The resulting workbook can be filled with the data and written to a new file with `workbook.SaveAs(newfilename).

Anything you do not touch explicitly is preserved. Excel is, of course, somewhat better at that than `xlrd`, `xlwt` and `xlutils`.