# Python, copy xls file with marking

Tags: python, excel, xlrd, xlwt, xlutils

I need to copy/edit existing sheet of xls file to new file with marking.
What i've tried:

```
import xlrd
from xlutils.copy import copy
workbook = xlrd.open_workbook('template1.xls')
new_wb = copy(workbook)
new_wb.save("test.xls")
```

But marking is not saved.
Existing file is something e.g.:
[image: Screenshot of existing xls file]

Result after "copy" is:
[image: Result of copying]

Help me please.

Comment: Not sure this is duplicate, but it's definitely related and could be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3723793/preserving-styles-using-pythons-xlrd-xlwt-and-xlutils-copy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best answer was in comments. I have reached answer limit, so need to set best answer.