# can I get the style of a cell of excel using xlrd

Tags: python-2.7, xlsx, xlrd, xlwt, xlsxwriter

I have an excel (xlsx) file and I am trying to read the style of the template, in order to copy the style to another excel file, using python xlrd, and xlwt library

how can I read the style from a cell?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `xlutils.copy` in order to be able to copy the style from one sheet to other one.

This question seems to be duplicated. Following [Preserving styles using python's xlrd,xlwt, and xlutils.copy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3723793/preserving-styles-using-pythons-xlrd-xlwt-and-xlutils-copy)

Comment: this is problematic since I am the template file is xls. but I have an xlsx.

Comment: How about trying openpyxl (https://openpyxl.readthedocs.org/en/latest/)

It provides 'Copying styles' tool too. This is what you need (https://openpyxl.readthedocs.org/en/latest/styles.html#copying-styles)

Comment: and if you are persisting to use `xlrd`, you need to upgrade `xlrd` version to `0.8.0`. use `pip install xlrd --upgrade`

Comment: what is is the change in the upgrade of the 0.8 version?

Comment: It supports `xlsx` files. You can visit the home page for more specific detail (http://www.python-excel.org/)