# Edit existing excel workbooks and sheets with xlrd and xlwt

Tags: python, excel, xlrd, xlwt

In the [documentation](http://www.simplistix.co.uk/presentations/python-excel.pdf) for `xlrd` and `xlwt` I have learned the following:

How to read from existing work-books/sheets:

```
from xlrd import open_workbook
wb = open_workbook("ex.xls")
s = wb.sheet_by_index(0)
print s.cell(0,0).value
#Prints contents of cell at location a1 in the first sheet in the document called ex.xls
```

How to create new work-books/sheets:

```
from xlwt import Workbook
wb = Workbook()
Sheet1 = wb.add_sheet('Sheet1')
Sheet1.write(0,0,'Hello')
wb.save('ex.xls')
#Creates a document called ex.xls with a worksheet called "Sheet1" and writes "Hello" to the cell located at a1
```

What I want to do now is to open an existing worksheet, in an existing workbook and write to that sheet.

I have tried something like:

```
from xlwt import open_workbook
wb = open_workbook("ex.xls")
s = wb.sheet_by_index(0)
print s.cell(0,0).value
```

but `open_workbook` is only part of the `xlrd` module, not `xlwt`.

Any ideas?

Edit1:
After Olivers suggestion I looked into `xlutils` and tried the following:

```
from xlrd import open_workbook
from xlwt import Workbook
from xlutils.copy import copy

wb = open_workbook("names.xls")
s = wb.get_sheet(0)
s.write(0,0,'A1')
wb.save('names.xls')
```

This however, gives me the following error message:

```
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\xlrd\book.py", line 655, in get_sheet
raise XLRDError("Can't load sheets after releasing resources.")
xlrd.biffh.XLRDError: Can't load sheets after releasing resources.
```

Edit 2:
The error message was due to improper use of the `get_sheet` function.
Finally found out how to use it:

```
from xlrd import open_workbook
from xlwt import Workbook
from xlutils.copy import copy

rb = open_workbook("names.xls")
wb = copy(rb)

s = wb.get_sheet(0)
s.write(0,0,'A1')
wb.save('names.xls')
```

Comment: Have you looked into the `xlutils` made by the same author and documented in the same document you're linking to? In the 2nd subsection of the "Writing Excel files", it is written that `Worksheets
Worksheets are created with the add_sheet method of the Workbook class.
To retrieve an existing sheet from a Workbook, use its get_sheet method. This method is particularly useful when the Workbook has been instantiated by xlutils.copy.
`

Comment: Hello Oliver, and thanks for the advice. I looked into `xlutils` and it sure seems to be what i'm looking for.

I still, however, can't seem to accomplish my goal.
When i use `get_sheet()` i get the following error message:
`File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\xlrd\book.py", line 655, in get_sheet
raise XLRDError("Can't load sheets after releasing resources.")
xlrd.biffh.XLRDError: Can't load sheets after releasing resources.`

Comment: Thanks, because you provide also the import clause in your code (it is often missing)

Answer (score 52, accepted):

As I wrote in the edits of the op, to edit existing excel documents you must use the `xlutils` module (Thanks Oliver)

Here is the proper way to do it:

```
#xlrd, xlutils and xlwt modules need to be installed.  
#Can be done via pip install <module>
from xlrd import open_workbook
from xlutils.copy import copy

rb = open_workbook("names.xls")
wb = copy(rb)

s = wb.get_sheet(0)
s.write(0,0,'A1')
wb.save('names.xls')
```

This replaces the contents of the cell located at a1 in the first sheet of "names.xls" with the text "a1", and then saves the document.

Comment: Thanks, but this solution works only for xls format. I tried using this for xlsx format but that corrupts the file. Luckily, I had a backup of the file so I could take that risk, but for those who don't, please make sure you use xls format.

Comment: Also it's worth noting that this process removes all color formatting and formulas from the spreadsheet.

Comment: @abaldwin99... Do you know any other method that can keep format and formula unchanged ?

Comment: @SagarMehta Been awhile but I believe I went the VBA macro route.  I have not personally used it but xlwings looks interesting depending on your use case... http://docs.xlwings.org/en/stable/udfs.html     edit:  Ah you need formatting too.  I think you need to go VBA unfortunately.

Comment: @SagarMehta Saving cell format (font, styles, colors) is simple http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3723793/preserving-styles-using-pythons-xlrd-xlwt-and-xlutils-copy . But looks like it is impossible to keep images and sheet formating, colontitles e.g.

Comment: Note that if your Workbook contains images, they will not be preserved in  the new/edited workbook :(

Answer (score 16):

Here's another way of doing the code above using the `openpyxl` module that's compatible with xlsx. From what I've seen so far, it also keeps formatting.

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook
wb = load_workbook('names.xlsx')
ws = wb['SheetName']
ws['A1'] = 'A1'
wb.save('names.xlsx')
```

Comment: As mentioned Above, if your Workbook contains images, they will not be preserved in the new/edited workbook.

Comment: Seems to work with xlsx, but at least for me, it irreparably corrupts xlsm.

Comment: Trying this in 2020 - hope it's been fixed, though I won't be working with xlsm just yet!