# How to Update xls file using python?

Tags: python, xls

I have one xls file named template.xls,which has some style and values,i want to insert a value in template.xls.How can i do this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26957831/edit-existing-excel-workbooks-and-sheets-with-xlrd-and-xlwt

Comment: Maybe this guide can help you: https://automatetheboringstuff.com/chapter12/

Comment: My .xls file has some style.It does not affect on copied xls file

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Edit existing excel workbooks and sheets with xlrd and xlwt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26957831/edit-existing-excel-workbooks-and-sheets-with-xlrd-and-xlwt)

Comment: Colors not affect on copied xls file

Answer (score -1):

There's already a thread related to your specific question.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/26958437/8751278

You should utilize this (from abaldwin99):

```
#xlrd, xlutils and xlwt modules need to be installed.  
#Can be done via pip install <module>
from xlrd import open_workbook
from xlutils.copy import copy

rb = open_workbook("names.xls")
wb = copy(rb)

s = wb.get_sheet(0)
s.write(0,0,'A1')
wb.save('names.xls')
```

However, you need to install the modules before it works.

It pretty much replaces the very top-left value and sets it to 'A1'.

You, of course, need to change 'names.xls' with your own file's name.

Comment: worth to note that this method will not conserve color formatting and formulas in the spreadsheet