# Python XLWT Module

Tags: python, xls, xlwt

I can't find any documentation on this module.

I have an ".xls" file. How do I open a workbook with this library? Or at least, how can I find a list of methods for this library?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know you can't open an xls file with xlwt. xlwt allows you to create a new excel workbook from scratch, add sheets, fill cells, and save it

See [Edit existing excel workbooks and sheets with xlrd and xlwt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26957831/edit-existing-excel-workbooks-and-sheets-with-xlrd-and-xlwt), if that's what you want to do