# Issues in preserving Excel formatting with Python's xlrd and xlutils

Tags: python, excel, xlrd, xlutils

Simply put, I would like to preserve all of the formatting of one Excel file into another. However, despite using the `formatting_info=True` flag, the formatting only appears for all of the unchanged cells within the changed row. Any advice?

```
import xlrd, xlutils
from xlrd import open_workbook
from xlutils.copy import copy

inBook = xlrd.open_workbook(r"path/to/file/format_input.xls", formatting_info=True, on_demand=True)
outBook = xlutils.copy.copy(inBook)

outBook.get_sheet(0).write(0,0,'changed!')
outBook.save(r"path/to/file/format_output.xls")
```

enter image description here

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`xlwt.write`](https://secure.simplistix.co.uk/svn/xlwt/trunk/xlwt/doc/xlwt.html?p=4966#xlwt.Worksheet.write-method) accept style informations as its third argument. Unfortunately, xlrd and xlwt use two very different XF object format. So you cannot directly copy the cell's style from the workbook read by `xlrd` to the workbook created by `xlwt`.

The workaround is the use an `xlutils.XLWTWriter` to copy the file, and then get back the style informations of *that* object to save the style of the cell you will update.

First you need that <strike>patch</strike> function by John Machin provided in [a very similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3723793/preserving-styles-using-pythons-xlrd-xlwt-and-xlutils-copy/5285650#5285650):

```
from xlutils.filter import process,XLRDReader,XLWTWriter

#
# suggested patch by John Machin
# https://stackoverflow.com/a/5285650/2363712
# 
def copy2(wb):
    w = XLWTWriter()
    process(
        XLRDReader(wb,'unknown.xls'),
        w
        )
    return w.output[0][1], w.style_list
```

Then in you main code:

```
import xlrd, xlutils
from xlrd import open_workbook
from xlutils.copy import copy

inBook = xlrd.open_workbook(r"/tmp/format_input.xls", formatting_info=True, on_demand=True)
inSheet = inBook.sheet_by_index(0)

# Copy the workbook, and get back the style
# information in the `xlwt` format
outBook, outStyle = copy2(inBook)

# Get the style of _the_ cell:    
xf_index = inSheet.cell_xf_index(0, 0)
saved_style = outStyle[xf_index]

# Update the cell, using the saved style as third argument of `write`:
outBook.get_sheet(0).write(0,0,'changed!', saved_style)
outBook.save(r"/tmp/format_output.xls")
```

Comment: Sylvain Leroux - sorry for the late reply. This is exactly what I needed. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

I had similar issues while using openpyxl - for some reason this just doesn't seem to handled very well in the modules available. I ended up just restyling the cells as needed after I had input my data, using the syntax below:

```
#Formatting
from openpyxl.styles import Style, Color, PatternFill, Alignment, Font, NumberFormat
#Allows for conditional formatting
from openpyxl.formatting import CellIsRule #Allows for Conditional Formatting

for cell in changed_cells:
    cell.style = Style(fill=PatternFill(patternType='solid', fgColor=Color('FFff8888')), 
                         font=Font(name="Arial",size=11), 
                         alignment=Alignment(horizontal="center"))
```

Info on the syntax for implementing this kind of thing with xlrd can be found [here](https://secure.simplistix.co.uk/svn/xlrd/trunk/xlrd/doc/xlrd.html?p=4966).

Comment: I appreciate the help, Alecg_O. I'm glad you pointed out the means of going about reformatting a cell. I'll keep this in mind going forward, but Sylvain Leroux offered a solution without the need of reformatting - which is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks again!