# How to preserve images in an xls sheet edited via xlrd?

Tags: python, excel, xls, xlrd

I'm using `xlrd` to edit a few cells in an Excel sheet (.xls). I'm able to preserve cell formatting of the edited info ([using this little hack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3723793/preserving-styles-using-pythons-xlrd-xlwt-and-xlutils-copy)). However, when the file is saved, all the images in the document are lost. Is there a way to keep them?

I know `xlsxwrite` can insert images into a worksheet, but the file in question isn't .xlsx, unfortunately.

Here's the code:

```
from xlrd import open_workbook
from xlutils.copy import copy

class Writetoxls(object):

    def __init__(self, ip, mac, ssid, wifipass, user, password):
        self.ip = ip
        self.mac = mac
        self.ssid = ssid
        self.wifipass = wifipass
        self.user = user
        self.password = password

        inBook = open_workbook('data.xls', formatting_info=True)
        outBook = copy(inBook)

        def _getOutCell(outSheet, colIndex, rowIndex):
            """ HACK: Extract the internal xlwt cell representation. """
            row = outSheet._Worksheet__rows.get(rowIndex)
            if not row: return None

            cell = row._Row__cells.get(colIndex)
            return cell

        def setOutCell(outSheet, col, row, value):
            """ Change cell value without changing formatting. """
            # HACK to retain cell style.
            previousCell = _getOutCell(outSheet, col, row)
            # END HACK, PART I

            outSheet.write(row, col, value)

            # HACK, PART II
            if previousCell:
                newCell = _getOutCell(outSheet, col, row)
                if newCell:
                    newCell.xf_idx = previousCell.xf_idx
                    # END HACK

        outSheet = outBook.get_sheet(0)
        setOutCell(outSheet, 3, 7, mac)
        setOutCell(outSheet, 4, 16, ssid)
        setOutCell(outSheet, 4, 17, wifipass)

        outBook.save('output.xls')
```

Thank you.