# Appending Data to an Excel file using Python without using openpyxl

Tags: python, excel

I am going to create a Excel application and I want to append the data to that Excel file without changing it's style openpyxl is giving a normal Excel so I want a different module to load with the previous styles and to save it

Also if some one know some example please share it

Comment: this will help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3723793/preserving-styles-using-pythons-xlrd-xlwt-and-xlutils-copy

Answer (score 0):

use xlsx writer this will open file without change in formatting you can save it back. as i have used it to save multiple file from a formatted template excel

```
pip install xlsxwriter
```